# Получение названия запускаемого файла Python

Tags: python

Как можно получить название файла который запускается?
Допустим есть файл main.py затем мы его запускаем и код возвращает название файла (: main.py).
Потом файл переименовывается в non.py и так же возвращение (: non.py)
Беглый поиск по гуглу не дал четкого ответа :c

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `sys.argv[0]` или `__file__` в зависимости от того, что конкретно вас интересует

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0].split('\\')[-1:][0])
```

*Спасибо.*